# Memory leaks in android

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I am developing an application that deals with storing lot of images in cache, I frequently encounter error like - out of memory. Can anyone suggest a way to deal with this issue

Error Log

```
Report of logcat :

06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:450)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:326)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at com.lht.icruise.activity.shipdetails.ShipDetailsActivity.onCreate(ShipDetailsActivity.java:99)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-27 19:41:16.425: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13965):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: MOre details? Error messages, code and so on...

Comment: Please post the stack trace from where you get the OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 1):

If you using large bitmaps,  recycling the bitmaps to free up memory using recycle() method on bitmap when that bitmap no more used, might help you.

Comment: As alternative (not so elegant) he can use`System.gc()` to free memory.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this answer helps you: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)